# How should I invalidate user access tokens in AngularFire/Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

**Context**

Using instructions for logging out users found [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-unauth) and [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/unauth.html).

I am using AngularFire with AngularJS, and authenticating users with the e-mail & password method.

**The Problem**

Calling `$unauth` does not invalidate a user's token: Subsequent calls to `$authWithPassword` return an identical authentication token.

Note: Tokens invalidate correctly after the expiration time set on the server.

**The Code**

```
angular
    .module('app')
    // Auth Factory
    .factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth", "FIREBASE_URI",
        function($firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URI) {
            var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);
            return $firebaseAuth(ref);
        }
    ])
```

Controller:

```
function authenticationCtrl($scope, $state, authService) {
    var authenticationCtrl = this;

    // LOGIN
    var login = function (userObject) {
        authService.loginWithPassword(userObject, function () {
            $state.go('[...]');
        },
        function (errorText) {
            // ERROR
            console.error("Error logging in user:", errorText)
        });
    };

    // LOGOUT
    var logout = function () {
        // Clear locally logged in user
        $scope.authData = null;
        authService.logout();
    };

    // PUBLIC
    return {
        login: login,
        logout: logout
    };
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('authenticationCtrl', authenticationCtrl)
```

Service:

```
function authService($state, FIREBASE_URI, Auth) {
    var model = this,
        ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);

    // LOGIN
    model.loginWithPassword = function(credentials, callBack, errorCallBack) {
        Auth.$authWithPassword(credentials)
            .then(function(authData) {
                model.cachedUser = authData;
                callBack();
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
            });
    };

    // LOGOUT
    model.logout = function() {
        Auth.$unauth();
        model.cachedUser = null;
        $state.go('common.login');
    };
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('authService', authService)
```

Comment: `$unauth` is not supposed to invalidate a token. It simply unauthenticates the client and clears the token from client side storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot manually invalidate a token if you're using Firebase's email & password authentication provider. The only way to do that is to use a [Custom Authentication implementation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) to generate tokens yourself. You can then invalidate a token by revoking the Firebase secret that was used to generate the token.